# win_copy giving error when using with_items

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use win_copy in a following fashion:

```
    win_copy:
      src: {{item}}_outputfile.txt
      dest: c:\temp{{ item }}_outputfile.csv
    with_items:
      {{ AnArrayOfValues }}
```

Now if the file does not exist Ansible giving error: FIleNotExist and it fails the script, but I want the Ansible script to continue and ignore the file which doesn't exist.
Any help in this regard?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ignore_errors: True` with the ansible modules.

Note:- `ignore_errors: True` will ignore all the error but in case of `win_copy` we can use this as there won't be many error except for `FIleNotExist`

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks: 
    - win_copy:
        src: "{{item}}_outputfile.txt"
        dest: c:\temp{{ item }}_outputfile.csv
      with_items:
        - "{{ AnArrayOfValues }}"
      ignore_errors: true
```

Comment: I know you just copy-pasta-ed the original question, but their yaml syntax is invalid by failing to quote those leading `{{` characters (in both cases, the `src:` and the `with_items:`)

Comment: @mdaniel thanks! usually I execute the code no matter however small/minimum it is but windows is an exception :)! I will be careful next time with my answer! Appreciate your inputs in this!